# Wicket 6 DefaultDataTable navigation don't work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.6

After porting from Wicket 1.5.x to 6.0.20 pages using DefaultDataTable don't work in navigation toolbar when viewed in Firefox (in Google Chrome is OK)

a) events OnClick() in java classes of Navigation Toolbar never hit
b) the whole Page is constructed new (recreated) after mouse click (in Firefox)

I'm not big hacker in AJAX events (EDIT) and event routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: Wicket & Firefox (mostly Firefox) always had a problem when some images are missing (no matter from application Java code, html or css)
Older post I have found is dated 2007

http://blog.tauren.com/2007/12/firefox-causes-wicket-to-re-render-page.html

Problem is not only with DataTable but for basic Link() { public void onClick() { }

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc of `DefaultDataTable` says:

> The `NavigationToolbar` and the `HeadersToolbar` are added as top
>   toolbars, while the `NoRecordsToolbar` toolbar is added as a bottom
>   toolbar.

I understand that this toolbars are not *ajaxified* toolbars, so you can try to add manually *ajaxfied* toolbars like this:

```
  DefaultDataTable dt = new DefaultDataTable(PANEL, null, null, FLAG_RESERVED1);
  dt.addTopToolbar(new AjaxFallbackHeadersToolbar(dt, null));
  dt.addTopToolbar(new AjaxNavigationToolbar(dt));
```